# Neovim how to call commands from Powershell?

Tags: processing, neovim

I am planning on using neovim as my primary text editor for my Processing sketches, so I need a way to conveniently run my Processing sketches from vim itself.

When I type in `processing-java --sketch="path" --run` in my powershell window, everything works as I expected. However, when I included the code below in my init.vim file, everytime I use the command, I receive `Error: Could not find or load main class processing.mode.java.Commander`

```
nnoremap <leader>r :call RunProcessingSketch()<CR>
function! RunProcessingSketch()
    execute "!processing-java.exe --sketch=" . getCwd(). " --run"
endfunction
```

Comment: I am very new to Neovim and have never tried this before, but I wonder if processing-java.exe gets executed with a different working directory in powershell vs neovim when you call it that way. I've had issues similar to this in AutoHotkey. It's run command for executing exes allows you to specify the working directory. It tends to need to either be the directory of data files you are working with or the directory of the exe itself. Idk if execute in neovim has something similar. Specifying the full path to the exe might have an effect too.